# What is a standalone application or a standalone server?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I am using jboss-as-7.1 which has two type of server option standalone and domain . But what does those mean ? Please give some easy real example .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually standalone means that the server needs nothing else to run it or there is only one server. Jboss standalone is for one server, but domain is for running multiple servers.
See: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7UserGuide

If an application doesn't need a server to run it or anything else to run it, then it is standalone. So a webapp would not be standalone.